# KeyError: {'input', 'agent_scratchpad'}

Tags: langchain

in this code when i ask anything it give me an error "KeyError: {'input', 'agent_scratchpad'}"
I want the gpt to search bing and give back results

```
def langchain_completion(self
                     ):

    system_template = """
        Your job is a financial advisor and assistant that must make decisions for users based on the user's data and the questions you ask. \
    """
    
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4",
                     temperature=self.TEMPERATURE,
                     max_tokens=self.USER_MAX_TOKENS
                    )

    tools = load_tools(["wikipedia", "llm-math", "bing-search"],
                       llm=llm
                      )
    
    my_agent = initialize_agent(tools,
                                 llm,
                                 agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
                                 verbose=False
                                )

    my_agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt.template = system_template

    
    while True:
        question = input("Enter your prompt: ")
        if (question != ""):
            print(my_agent.run(input=question))
        else:
            return "I'm Out"
```

The error:

File ~\miniconda3\envs\workspace\Lib\site-packages\langchain\utils\formatting.py:18, in StrictFormatter.check_unused_args(self, used_args, args, kwargs)
16 extra = set(kwargs).difference(used_args)
17 if extra:
---> 18     raise KeyError(extra)

KeyError: {'input', 'agent_scratchpad'}

Answer (score 1):

the error was about changing the original system prompt template without considering the input variables

so

```
my_agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt.template += system_template
```

should fix it